# Ubuntu unlock ssh key at every usage

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-keys

I have an SSH private key and I would like to be asked for the password every time if it is used.
I don't know how to do this...

Thank you!

Comment: if you use it to connect through SSH and it has a passphrase, the passphrase should be asked every time, unless you use ssh-agent (or something like it).

Comment: I just have to unlock it once - I use it for GIT, sftp, SSH,...

Comment: I think you have to specify if a passphrase when you generate the key. I don't think you can add one later.

Comment: It has a passphrase - I am asked once and after then the key is unlocked until I reboot my machine

Comment: are you sure ssh-agent is not running?
also, try to list files in your `~/.ssh` dir after it's been cached.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ssh-agent. Make sure ssh-agent is started on your machine and add your private key to the ssh-agent with:

`$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`